# python mapi messages collection getfirst() returns second and not the first message

Tags: python, outlook

I'm working with Outlook, using mapi library and Python. I try to get the first message out of few similar messages( only subject is different). Somehow, I get second message only. Here is my code:

```
self.outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
self.mapi = self.outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
folderHandle = self.mapi.GetDefaultFolder(folder)
messages = folderHandle.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
```

The subject of the message I get -is the subject of the second email in the list( the email are similar except the subject), instead of the first message subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items collection is not sorted in any particular order until you explicitly call `Items.Sort`.